# Why Are Ember Models Named Differently Than Everything Else?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, naming-conventions, ember-data

In Ember, everything is registered with its type as part of the name. i.e.:

```
App.FoobarController
App.FoobarView
App.FoobarRoute
```

Except for Ember-Data models, which are all just called by their root name. i.e.

```
App.User
App.Post
App.Comment
```

Why do ember-data models break this pattern instead of being called `App.UserModel`, `App.PostModel`, `App.CommentModel` respectively?

I realize that I can name my models anything I want, but if I go ahead and name my user model `App.UserModel`, then all my AJAX requests are sent to `/user_models` and expect response JSON with a root element of `user_model`/`user_models`. I also realize that its possible to register aliases/plurals to make this pattern possible.

But, I can do things like `controllerName: 'Foobar'` and `templateName: 'Foobar'`, and Ember automagically resolves them to `FoobarController` and `FoobarTemplate` respectively. I can also define `App.FoobarView` and `App.FoobarController` and Ember knows that they go together and pairs them up automatically. That said, I would expect the same type of magic to happen for AJAX requests for `UserModel` to be rewritten to `/users` and to enable fetching via `App.store.find( 'User', 123 )`.

Is there a reason this convention has been broken when dealing with models, or is this just an oversight/error/inconsistency with Ember-Data?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a reason this convention has been broken when dealing with models, or is this just an oversight/error/inconsistency with Ember-Data?

I think the convention is not so much broken as it is different that what you expect. In many ways ember is building on conventions used by rails and other MVC frameworks. Typically MVC applications are built around a set of objects that represent the *domain model*. For example:

```
User, Post, Comment, etc.
```

Now for each model there are other framework-specific objects that may be needed, like:

```
UserController, UserView, UserPresenter, UserMailer, UserTemplate, UserView
```

So following this convention UserModel would not make sense. I can see an argument that `UserModel` would be more clear but would recommend picking your battles. Trying to fight the framework (be it ember, rails, or any other) and use your own naming conventions will result in a lot of extra work. Would recommend going with the defaults unless you've got money to burn or a really good reason.